# wso2 api manager token Revocation doesn't work in cluster mode

Tags: jwt, wso2, access-token, wso2-api-manager

I'm using from wso2 api manager 4.1.0 that deployed with a [Configuring an Active-Active Deployment](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-an-active-active-deployment/)
I want to revoke access token and I used the [revoke API](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/design/api-security/oauth2/token-revocation/) to revoke the token and I got 200 response But the token still works!

also, I added `notification_endpoint = "https://[control-plane-host]:[port]/internal/data/v1/notify"` configuration  and make `[apim.cache_invalidation]`
to `true` in deployment.toml
But the token did not expire!

When I call r got this Error:

```
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    | [2024-01-24 15:03:07,193] ERROR - EventJunction Error while dispatching events: No HazelcastInstance found.
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    | java.lang.RuntimeException: No HazelcastInstance found.
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService.getClusterTimeInMillis(CarbonEventManagementService.java:391) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.EventPublisher.sendEvent(EventPublisher.java:216) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.EventPublisher.onEvent(EventPublisher.java:300) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.event.stream.core.internal.EventJunction.sendEvent(EventJunction.java:157) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.event.stream.core.internal.EventStreamRuntime.publish(EventStreamRuntime.java:92) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.event.stream.core.internal.CarbonEventStreamService.publish(CarbonEventStreamService.java:356) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.eventing.hub.EventHubEventStreamServiceEventPublisher.publish(EventHubEventStreamServiceEventPublisher.java:47) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.eventing.hub_9.20.74.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.publishEvent_aroundBody776(APIUtil.java:10416) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.publishEvent(APIUtil.java:10413) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification.TokenRevocationNotifierImpl.sendMessageOnRealtime(TokenRevocationNotifierImpl.java:75) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification_9.20.74.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.publishers.RevocationRequestPublisher.publishRevocationEvents_aroundBody2(RevocationRequestPublisher.java:72) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.publishers.RevocationRequestPublisher.publishRevocationEvents(RevocationRequestPublisher.java:67) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification.AbstractKeyManagerEventHandler.handleTokenRevocationEvent(AbstractKeyManagerEventHandler.java:58) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification_9.20.74.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification.DefaultKeyManagerEventHandlerImpl.handleTokenRevocationEvent(DefaultKeyManagerEventHandlerImpl.java:53) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification_9.20.74.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification.DefaultKeyManagerEventHandlerImpl.handleEvent(DefaultKeyManagerEventHandlerImpl.java:39) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification_9.20.74.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification.NotificationEventService.processEvent(NotificationEventService.java:44) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification_9.20.74.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.internal.service.impl.NotifyApiServiceImpl.notifyPost(NotifyApiServiceImpl.java:29) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.internal.service.NotifyApi.notifyPost(NotifyApi.java:47) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279) ~[?:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:58) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
am_api-manager-node2.1.crv93twsf7h0@    |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using the public APIM 4.1.0 pack? Did you use Hazelcast clustering or just 2 all-in-one setups? Is the token revoked in one gateway or is it not revoked in both instances?

Comment: @HeshanSudarshana yes I am, I'm using just 2 all-in-one setups (which I have mentioned in the body of the question). It's not revoked in both instances.